# Why would an insert from a select with an serial pk in Postgres produce a duplicate pk error when the pk is excluded from the insert?

Tags: sql, postgresql, metadata

I'm running Posgres 8.4 and I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE communitynetwork_listitem
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "MdUsr" integer,
  "MdDT" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "CrUsr" integer,
  "CrDT" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  category_id character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  "name" character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  "order" integer NOT NULL,
  "extraInfo" boolean NOT NULL,
  "multiLineInfo" boolean NOT NULL,
  "descrLabel" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  "decimalReq" boolean NOT NULL,
  "decimalLabel" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  "decimalLabelDisplay" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  "descrLabelDisplay" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT communitynetwork_listitem_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "category_id_refs_catId_69f2992c" FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
      REFERENCES communitynetwork_listcategory ("catId") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT communitynetwork_listitem_category_id_64fdc58a_uniq UNIQUE (category_id, name)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

When I tried to run the following query it gave me an error saying that I was violating the communitynetwork_listitem_pkey constraint. Any idea why that might be?

```
insert into communitynetwork_listitem ("MdUsr", "MdDT", "CrUsr", "CrDT", category_id, name, "order", "extraInfo", "multiLineInfo", "descrLabel", "decimalReq", "decimalLabel", "decimalLabelDisplay", "descrLabelDisplay")
select "MdUsr", "MdDT", "CrUsr", "CrDT", category_id, name, 0, "extraInfo", "multiLineInfo", "descrLabel", "decimalReq", "decimalLabel", "decimalLabelDisplay", "descrLabelDisplay"
  from communitynetwork_listitem_import liImp
 where not exists (select *
                     from communitynetwork_listitem li
                    where li.name = liImp.name
                      and li.category_id = liImp.category_id)
```

Comment: I'm surprised by the communitynetwork_listitem_pkey violation but I could see a violation on communitynetwork_listitem_category_id_64fdc58a_uniq if (name, category) are not unique in the source table

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had previously done an insert that had included id values that I knew where unique. Doing that does not increment the sequence that is used to increment the primary key value. Updating the sequence value fixed the problem.